# Strange result when summing the tables

Tags: r

I am running some calculations in r

```
df1 <- data.frame( data=mydata6$Date.created, mydata6[,-1] +  mydataADDtasks[,-1])
```

code is running, no mistake is given. when i write

```
View(df1)
```

i see a table length 16, 5 obs of 16 variables.

But when I check

```
summarise (df1)
```

data frame with 0 columns and 1 row

And obviously i can not do any calculations with dataset. What should i do? What is wrong???

Comment: did you perhaps want `summary` instead of `summarise`?

Comment: `summarise` is a function for calculating new summaries from the data frame. Since you provided it a data frame but no other arguments (no calculations), the function returns an empty data frame.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behavior of the `dplyr::summarise` function. You have no group combination, so it returns an empty dataframe. You could use `group_by` and return a non-empty dataframe.

```
mtcars |> 
  dplyr::group_by(mpg) |> 
  dplyr::summarise(sum_cyl = sum(cyl))
```

There's probably nothing wrong with your dataframe!

You could also get an output from no grouping variables, but you still would need to supply a function to get an output:

```
dplyr::summarise(mtcars, sum_cyl = sum(cyl))
```

Maybe what you are after is `summary`?

```
> summary(mtcars)
      mpg             cyl             disp             hp             drat             wt       
 Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0   Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513  
 1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5   1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581  
 Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0   Median :3.695   Median :3.325  
 Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7   Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217  
 3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0   3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610  
 Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0   Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424  
      qsec             vs               am              gear            carb      
 Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median :17.71   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
 Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375   Mean   :0.4062   Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
 3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
 Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000
```